# Issue with Scrolling in Hybrid iOS app Appium

Tags: ios, scroll, appium, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm trying to scroll the screen with but give me error that there is no such element in the view. I have tried some other ways but also fail to scroll to that row. I have no id-s because the rows are making dynamically and i only can scroll to particular element by "partialLinkText" property

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
scrollObject.put("direction", "down");
scrollObject.put("element", ((RemoteWebElement) driver.findelement(by.partialLinkText("Flow")).getId());
js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);
```

I have row with Text in it that is "Flow" but I can't find a way to scroll to that particular text . In Android it work with moveTo  method , but in iOS it seems that it doesnt work. 
This is how I scroll to a row on the screen I am looking for :

```
    WebElement flow= driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Flow"));

    Actions action = new Actions(driver);

    // Scroll to Flow Row
    action.moveToElement(flow).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is way to scroll, it will scroll page not to the specific element, you can control it by changing `coordinate` and `UP/DOWN` as per your needs.

```
driver.executeScript("seetest:client.swipe(\"Down\", 700, 500)");
```

This script will execute if you use Appium Studio as Appium server

Comment: I am looking for a way , how to scroll to particular text or field . in My cause with partialLinkText , and want not to use coordinates